# How can I "SCRIPT FLUSH" with Redigo?

Tags: go

I try to flush the scripts using the command:" SCRIPT FLUSH" running the code like this:

```
c.Send("SCRIPT FLUSH")
c.Flush()
spew.Dump(c.Receive())
```

But I get this output:

```
(interface {}) <nil>
(redis.Error) (len=33) ERR unknown command 'SCRIPT FLUSH'
```

When I run the command from the command line I get an OK response:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two arguments:

```
c.Send("SCRIPT", "FLUSH")
c.Flush()
spew.Dump(c.Receive())
```

Also, use Do instead of the Send/Flush/Receive calls:

```
spew.Dump(c.Do("SCRIPT", "FLUSH"))
```